# Centering navigation bar in CSS

Tags: html, css, web, center, navigationbar

First I need to tell you that I tried other posts, but unfortunately none works. I have a navigation bar and I want to have the "HOME" button starting in the middle of the navigation bar, basically 4 buttons centered. 
Thanks for help. All HTML and CSS here: jsfiddle.net/bqcuu3dk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height` and `line-height` to your navbar, and `text-align` to center.

```css
#navbar {
  height: 43px;
  line-height: 43px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font: normal 15px Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #d1d1d1;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#navbar a.active:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.65;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <a class="active" href="#index">Home</a>
  <a href="#nav1">Nav1</a>
  <a href="#nav2">Nav2</a>
  <a href="#nav3">Nav3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can even use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this updated CSS:

```
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font: normal 15px Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #595959;
  color: #d1d1d1;
}

#navbar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#navbar a.active:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.65;
}
```

Comment: Hey, you should add a display: inline-block; to keep the padding styles.